# How do I fix WordPress PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : plugins error?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cpanel

So I am trying to install recommended plugins from a WordPress theme after installing the theme but the plugins installing return errors. Below is the response for contact form 7:

> Downloading installation package from
> [https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.5.2.1.zip…](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.5.2.1.zip%E2%80%A6)
> Unpacking the package… The package could not be installed.
> PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : Missing archive file
> '/tmp/contact-form-7.5.2.1-ribBpT.tmp'

I read some inputs about adding some lines of codes into the wp-config file and adding the below and created a folder called "temp" under the contents folder:

```
/*Set WordPress temporary directory */
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/temp');
```

I then went back to refresh before I tried installing the plugin but the issue remained the same.

Here is what I have in the wp-config file:

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
/*Set WordPress temporary directory */
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/temp');
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

Am I missing anything here? If yes, how do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might happen when you do not have space left on your disk drive. Check this with `df -h`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Your wp-content folder. You can access the wp-content folder by using a file manager on your hosting or using FTP. The location will be domain/wp-content (where domain is the website domain name)
2. When you are in wp-content create new folder under wp-content and call it temp.
3. Download your wp-config file from your server to your computer. This is just in case you make a mistake and have a backup which you can quickly restore. Open the wp-config file and search for the following line of code.

*if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
define('ABSPATH', dirname(**FILE**) . '/');*

4. Add following line of code after that line.

****/*Set WordPress temporary directory */
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/temp');****

5. Save the wp-config.php file. If you edited it on your PC upload it to the website

Answer (score 0):

just add `define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/temp');` right after `}`!
and create `temp` folder in `wp-content/temp`.
if put cod inside `{}` won't work
somthing like this will work:

```
 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );

}
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/temp');
```